# Setting background color for UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uialertcontroller

I am using the new `UIAlertController` to implement an options menu of sorts for my application. I am trying to get the background color of the `UIAlertController` to match the theme of the rest of my application. The theme for my application is pretty simple, and consists of white text with a blue/grey background color for the toolbar and navigation bar, shown below:

[image]

However, I am having some trouble trying to get my `UIAlertController` to conform to this theme. I made the the following two calls to set the text and background color:

```
uiAlertController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(.17255), green: CGFloat(.24314), blue: CGFloat(.31373), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
uiAlertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

This changed the `UIAlertController` to look like below:

[image]

The text was changed from the default blue system color to white, but the background color is not correct. I also tried modifying the specifying opacity (`uiAlertController.view.opaque = true`) but this did not help either. How do I go about setting the background color so it matches my navigation bar and toolbar? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for Swift 3 Xcode 8.2.1

```
let subview = (alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!)! as UIView

                subview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (145/255.0), green: (200/255.0), blue: (0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)

                alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

[image]

Comment: how to change text colour?

Comment: alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
if want some thing else tell me will tell

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed how to change particular button font color?

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed How to change the divider color in action sheet alert controller

Comment: what about ActionSheet

Comment: Well, this is worked for me on Xcode 10, iOS 12. But what this ```alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!``` mean exactly?

Answer (score 3):

## Setting background color for UIAlertController in Swift

All you have to do is this:

//Create your alert controller

...

// Setting background color

```
let backView = yourAlertController.view.subviews.last?.subviews.last
backView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
backView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor() 

self.presentViewController(yourAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.  Turns out I needed to traverse the subview tree like so:

```
var subView = alertController.view.subviews.first as! UIView
var contentView = subView.subviews.first as! UIView
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 233.0/255.0, green: 133.0/255.0, blue: 49.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```